# awk manipulates csv file

Tags: shell, csv, awk

I want to use awk to read a csv file. The csv file contains 5 columns, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5. I want judge the c1, c2 and c3 together is unique, like database constraint.

here is sample csv file:

```
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5
1886,5141,11-2011,62242.57,52.71
1886,5140,11-2011,63763.75,52.22
23157666,4747,11-2011,71.07,83.33
1886,5141,11-2011,4645.45,2135.45
```

In this case, row1 and row4 violate the unique constraint, and prompt the error message.

How to implement it with awk? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This lists *all* the lines for each duplication. It only outputs the duplication message *once* for each set.

```
awk -F, '{count[$1,$2,$3]++; line[$1,$2,$3] = line[$1,$2,$3] ", " NR} END {for (i in count) {if (count[i] > 1) {v=i; gsub(SUBSEP, FS, v); print "Error: lines", substr(line[i], 3), "collide on value:", v}}}'
```

Broken out on multiple lines:

```
awk -F, '
    {
        count[$1,$2,$3]++; 
        line[$1,$2,$3] = line[$1,$2,$3] ", " NR
    }
    END {
        for (i in count) {
            if (count[i] > 1) {
                v = i;
                gsub(SUBSEP, FS, v);
                print "Error: lines", substr(line[i], 3), "collide on value:", v
            }
        }
    }'
```

This is a variation on Kevin's answer.

Comment: Thanks,Dennis. I appreciate your time.

Comment: Hi Dennis. The script works at my home machine. But it shows "awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1
" at work. Is there any awk version variance? Thank you.

Comment: There shouldn't be any syntax difference. This script runs under `gawk` with or without the `--traditional` (or `--posix`) options so it should work in other versions of AWK. What OS/distributions are you using and what versions of AWK? By the way, there is an error in my answer that shouldn't be related to the syntax error. It's simply an incorrect index. I'll correct my answer.

Comment: Hi Dennis, I man awk. It shows "SunOS 5.9            Last change: 7 Jul 2000". Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: The OS is Solaris9. I cannot find a way to find the awk version. awk --version does not work.

Comment: @AlexTang: Try `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` instead of `/usr/bin/awk` on Solaris to see if it works. I think the problem may be that the primary AWK on Solaris doesn't support pseudo-multidimensional arrays. You can also try replacing `$1,$2,$3` with `$1 SUBSEP $2 SUBSEP $3` in each of the three places it appears and adding `BEGIN {SUBSEP = "\034"}` before the first open curly brace. This should emulate the multidimensional array feature. If `\034` (octal for ASCII FS) doesn't work, try using a regular character that doesn't appear in your data (`|` might be a good choice).

Answer (score 5):

```
awk -F, 'line[$1,$2,$3] {printf "Error: lines %d and %d collide\n", line[$1,$2,$3], NR; next} {line[$1,$2,$3] = NR}'
```

Comment: +1  That's a nice trick.  I wasn't aware that worked.  Seems obvious in retrospect.